# uksort() function not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in PHP using a custom function, but it's not working. Here is the (simplified) code I'm using:

```
        class Test {

            public function sortByVote($a, $b) {
                $v1 = $a['voteCount'];
                $v2 = $b['voteCount'];
                if ($v1 > $v2) return +1;
                if ($v1 < $v2) return -1;
                return 0;
            }

            function test() {
                $temp = array(
                    array("voteCount" => 1),
                    array("voteCount" => 4),
                    array("voteCount" => 9),
                    array("voteCount" => 2),
                    array("voteCount" => 3)
                );

                uksort($temp, array($this, "sortByVote"));
            }

        }
```

Can anybody see what the issue is?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you may really want usort instead of uksort.  Hard to tell with limited info though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`uksort()`](http://php.net/uksort) sorts the *keys*. In your example, the keys are just automatically generated numeric keys from 0 - 4. I think you mean to sort by *values* using [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort). Or, if you're looking to maintain index association but still sort by the values, you're looking for [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort). In short, your sort is borked.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed needed usort()

Answer (score 1):

You need usort() (user sort by values), not uksort() (user sort by keys)
uksort's callback receives the keys of elements in $temp
usort's callback receives the values of elements in $temp

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use ***usort*** to sort this array the way you want it.

```
class Test {
   private $myArray = [];

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->myArray = [
         array("voteCount" => 1),
         array("voteCount" => 4),
         array("voteCount" => 9),
         array("voteCount" => 2),
         array("voteCount" => 3)
     ];
   }

  private function sortByVote($a, $b)
  {
    return $a <=> $b;
  }

  public function myArray()
  {
    return $this->myArray;
  }

  public function mySort()
  {
    return usort($this->myArray, 'Test::sortByVote');
  }

}

$t = new Test;
$t->mySort();

$result = $t->myArray();
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [voteCount] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [voteCount] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [voteCount] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [voteCount] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [voteCount] => 9
    )

)
```